# How to send data from server without disturbing client sending continuous data

Tags: python, tcp, tcpserver

I have made an python program to receive data send by device to the server and the device send data every 2 second to the server now my question is how to send data from server to client without disturbing client which is sending continuous data

```
import socket



# get the hostname
host = socket.gethostname()
port = 5000  # initiate port no above 1024

server_socket = socket.socket()  # get instance
# look closely. The bind() function takes tuple as argument
server_socket.bind((host, port))  # bind host address and port together

# configure how many client the server can listen simultaneously
server_socket.listen(2)
conn, address = server_socket.accept()  # accept new connection
print("Connection from: " + str(address))
while True:
    # receive data stream. it won't accept data packet greater than 1024 bytes
    data = conn.recv(1024).decode()
    if not data:
        # if data is not received break
        break
    print("from connected user: " + str(data))
    data = input(' -> ')
    conn.send(data.encode())  # send data to the client

conn.close()  # close the connection
```

But the problem with this code is it wait for the input if we don't provide input,code does not read the data send by client device .